# paper-toolbar does not center content

Tags: css, polymer

I want to center the title and navigation links in my paper-toolbar. I am using the properties "justify" and "bottomJustify" to accomplish this, but the content remains on the left side.

```
<paper-toolbar class="medium-tall" justify="center" bottomJustify="center">
    <div class="title">Titel</div>
    <div class="bottom">
       <a data-route="contact" href="contact">
          <span>Contact</span>
       </a>
   </div>
</paper-toolbar>
```

It does not matter which "tallness" I choose. It never works. Does anyone has an idea how to solve this?

---

**Update:**

This code works:

```
   <paper-toolbar class="medium-tall" justify="center" bottom-justify="center">
        <div class="top">
            Title
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <a data-route="contact" href="contact">
                <span>Contact</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </paper-toolbar>
```

I had to:

- change the bottomJustify to bottom-justify
- remove the "title" class and instead use the "top" class

Comment: thanks for the update!

Comment: also, in the future, be careful when using an attribute from a property: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#property-name-mapping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you should use `bottom-justify` instead of `bottomJustify` to set the attribute!

Comment: It worked, thank you! The top alignment did not work because of the "title" class.

Comment: @user32323 if you had some special things in the title class (say font color or whatever) you can still use it as well as top, class="top title". You can have as many classes as you like just space separated.